# Xcode crashing when opening up gamescene.sks file

Tags: macos, mac, crash, vmware, xcode

I am running Xcode 10.3 on Mac OS 10.14.6 on VMware Workstation 15 player. I am trying to learn the spritekit framework for 2d drawing and animation. This means that a file is automatically generated called GameScene.sks. When attempting to open this file through Xcode, it results in a crash (Xcode closes and a box appears labeled "Xcode quit unexpectedly"). I am able to open the other .sks file in my project that is Actions.sks

I have tried a solution that I found on a different website that said to input this command into terminal but it still didn't work 
"sudo codesign -f -s - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode "

Hardware:
intel i7 8700k
16gb ddr4 ram
nvidia 1070ti

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the use of macOS on non-Apple hardware is a legal grey area and as a result "Hackintosh" questions have been deemed [off-topic](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1471/are-hackintosh-questions-allowed).

Comment: I am having the same issue on my MacBook Pro